# Centering variables for interaction, continuous x catagorical (2 levels)

Tags: regression, interaction, multicollinearity

For a multiple regression analyses I'm looking to assess whether an effect of a contiuous independent variable on a continuous dependent variable is different between two levels of a catagorical independent variable. The regression looks like this:

education+brain size+age+sex+[brain size x sex]=cognition

I want to assess whether the effect of brain size on cognition is different between the sexes (male vs female) but i'm unsure whether i need to center the continuous variable "brain size" to avoid multicollinearity.

Answer (score 2):

You won't solve multicolinearity that way, it is just a linear transformation. However, you do improve the interpretation of the main effect of sex. Without centering it will be the effect of sex for someone without a brain (brainsize=0), which is not really useful. If you center your brainsize variable you will get the effect of sex for someone with an average size brain.